# Como salvar um JSON localmente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**Pergunta direta: *Qual a melhor maneira de salvar um arquivo JSON localmente e como fazê-lo?***

Detalhes: Tenho uma aplicação web que recebe dados do usuário utilizando a API do Facebook (Javascript SDK), preciso salvar estes dados em um arquivo JSON localmente. Depois de salvo, passo para a aplicação escrita em liguagem C que irá abrir e interpretar este JSON para que os dados sejam salvos em um banco de dados (SQLite3).

Comment: Pode ser no cache do navegador?

Comment: Não, preciso que seja na máquina mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso esteja procurando por uma solução client-side apenas, uma opção é o [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
var objteste = { 'um': 1, 'dois': 2, 'tres': 3 };

// Armazena no LocalStorage
localStorage.setItem('objteste', JSON.stringify(objteste));

// Obtém do LocalStorage
var objSalvo = localStorage.getItem('objteste');

console.log('objSalvo: ', JSON.parse(objSalvo));
```

Entretanto você menciona banco de dados - o que implica em um serviço web. Em C#, por exemplo, você pode serializar um objeto e utiliar o FileSystem como um cache antes de enviá-lo para o banco:

```
var _data = new 
{
    um = 1,
    dois = 2,
    tres = 3
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"C:\objeto.json", json);
```

Fontes: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921652/how-to-write-a-json-file-in-c).